# MySQL Trigger обновление данных в таблице, на событие UPDATE

Tags: mysql

Нужно сделать MySQL триггер срабатывающий на AFTER UPDATE в таблице, и вызывающий оператор UPDATE в этой же таблице. Вопрос в следующем, не превратится ли подобный запрос в бесконечный цикл? Пример:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `something` AFTER UDPATE ON `table`
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
 UPDATE `table` SET `column` = 1
END
```

///////Пример запроса через BEFORE, будет ли он правильно работать?/////////

```
CREATE TRIGGER `something` BEFORE UDPATE ON `table`
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
 UPDATE `table` SET `b` = CASE
    WHEN `a` = 1 THEN 'true'
    WHEN `a` = 0 THEN 'false'
    END
END
```

Comment: Не превратиться, mysql просто выдаст ошибку при попытке модификации той же таблицы на которую триггер. Необходимо искать другой подход. Опишите для чего вы хотите это делать

Comment: Есть стороннее программное обеспечение, которое редактирует значение в столбце этой таблицы (Предположительно используя UPDATE). Хотелось бы отлавливать момент когда ПО меняет это значение и также изменять данные в другом столбце этой же таблицы (уже в существующей записи).

Comment: т.е. менять надо значение в другой записи этой таблицы ?

Comment: Одна и таже запись, ПО меняет значение в столбце `a`, а триггером нужно менять значение в столбце `b`

Comment: тогда делайте триггер BEFORE и меняйте поле в записи которая будет записана с помощью `set NEW.b = ...` (set это самостоятельный оператор, а не часть конструкции update)

Comment: Прошу прощения, моя ошибка, забыл упомянуть о том, что значение `b`, зависит от `a`. Т.е мне нужно сначала узнать чему равно `a` после обновления и уже опираясь на это значение, изменять `b`.
Например: 
Если `a` = 1, то `b` будет true
Если `a` = 0, то `b` будет false.
Планировал перебирать это через CASE, с помощью UPDATE.

Я добавил второй пример к основному вопросу. Будет ли это выражение правильно работать?

Comment: Принципиальный вопрос: вам нужно изменить значение этой же самой строки? Тогда не делаете update в триггере, а меняете саму структуру NEW.  Если вам нужно изменить другую строку этой же таблицы - то это много приключений, нативно в mysql такое просто запрещено.

Comment: @summoner38 Обратите внимание, ваш пример с update меняет вообще все строки в таблице, потому что нет where. Все поля записи, которая будет записана на диск, доступны в before триггере через `NEW.поле`, таким образом ваш триггер буквально сводиться к (дословно): `BEGIN SET NEW.b = case NEW.a when 1 then 'true' when 0 then 'false' end; END` Т.е. вы просто меняете в оперативной памяти ту переменную, которая после завершения триггера будет записана на диск. И никаких update